# Alamofire complaining about argument types

Tags: swift, http, alamofire

In the code below, Alamofire is complaining that it "Cannot invoke 'responseJSON' with an argument list of type ((_, _, _, _) -> _)." The same issue occurs when using 'response.'

```
    func request(parameters: [String : AnyObject?], completionHandler: ((NSURLRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse?, AnyObject?, NSError?) -> Void)) -> Void {
      Alamofire.request(.POST, "localhost:8080/reserve", parameters:
            ["refreshToken": refreshToken,
             "accessToken": accessToken,
             "deviceToken": deviceToken],
            encoding: .JSON)
      .responseJSON { (request, response, data, error) in
            completionHandler(request, response, data, error)
      }
   }
```

Why is this occuring?

Comment: Which version are you using (for alamofire, swift and xcode) ? It works fine here with the last version version of alamofire, swift 1.2 and xcode 6.3

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your `parameters` argument is bad typed. It should be `[String: AnyObject]?` instead of `[String : AnyObject?]`.

Fixing this error, you should be able to compile again.

Otherwise, ensure your token variables exist. If not, the compiler is confused, and the error is not actually due to Alamofire.